# Por que me marca error

Tags: c#

Quiero enviar un correo pero me marca error al enviarlo

```
 string servidor = "smtp.gmail.com";
        MailMessage mensaje = new MailMessage(origen, destino, asunto, msg);
        Attachment Archivoadjunto = new Attachment(adjunto);
        mensaje.Attachments.Add(Archivoadjunto);
        using (SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient())
        {
            cliente.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            cliente.Port = 587;
            cliente.Host = servidor;
            cliente.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(origen, " ");
            cliente.EnableSsl = true;
            cliente.Send(mensaje);
        }
```

Ya active el acceso a apps menos seguras pero me sigue marcando este error

El servidor SMTP requiere una conexión segura o el cliente no se autenticó. La respuesta del servidor fue: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta mandar el usuario y la contraseña en esta línea de código:
`smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");`

Comment: Ahora me marca: SocketException: Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder